# Getting the MAC address and IP address of device from Android app

Tags: android, ip-address, mac-address, android-networking

How can I obtain the MAC and IP addresses of the device from an Android application?

Answer (score 3):

```
 public static String getMacAddr(Context appContext) {
    WifiManager manager=(WifiManager) appContext.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    WifiInfo info=manager.getConnectionInfo();
    String m_macAddr=info.getMacAddress();
    return m_macAddr;
}
```

- Try this.